# Wordpress - Page2 duplication

Tags: wordpress-theming, wordpress

I'm having an issue with my WordPress theme and would be very grateful if anyone could help me resolve it.

The issue is Page2 is a duplicate of the homepage.

Website:
http://www.ido.co.uk

Issue:
add /page/2/ to above URL

Dirty fix is to 301 page2 however would rather work out whats wrong.

Pastebin of homepage - http://pastebin.com/MkMjnGpc

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: How did you set this page to be the homepage?

Comment: This is set via the theme frame work, here is a pastebin to the actual index file http://pastebin.com/kznWQNeD

Comment: when you go to settings >> reading, what is the setting for your homepage, a static page or all the posts?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, its set to "Your latest posts"

Comment: Try setting it to a static page?

Comment: Thanks but that will break the theme

Answer (score 0):

Your homepage displays the list of all posts. By default, wordpress allows to view old posts by creating urls like: /page/2 or /page/X. All of these urls essentially do what the homepage does.

Not knowing enough about your theme, I don't know how easy it would be to display this page as a static page as oppose to a list of all posts. So presumably, redirecting /page/X to the homepage is the easier solution for you...